# AccessDeniedException when trying to login as guest user in AWS Webrtc sample

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, webrtc

I was testing the sample app for AWS Webrtc from the given link, [AWS Webrtc iOS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams-webrtc-dg/latest/devguide/kvswebrtc-sdk-ios.html). The sample is working fine when the user is authenticated. I was planning to implement guest user functionality but i am getting the following issue:

Error creating channel Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSKinesisVideoErrorDomain Code=1 "null" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=null, NSLocalizedFailureReason=AccessDeniedException:[http://internal.amazon.com/coral/com.amazon.coral.service/}](http://internal.amazon.com/coral/com.amazon.coral.service/%7D)

I have enabled the guest user option in the identity pool. Is there something more I have to do to get the webrtc sample working without the user logging in.